# Why can't I access JSON objects by key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This is my JSON object:

```
{ text: 'stuff',
  user: 'user1
}
```

when I run a `typeof jsonObj`, I get `object`. When I run an `jsonOb.length`, I get undefined. When I tried to access the `text` property via `console.log(jsonObj.text)`, I get undefined.

So how can I properly access everything in JavaScript?

I don't want to use jQuery as this is all `node.js` programming so it's serverside.

**UPDATED** - full JSON

```
{ text: '@junk_666 おかえりか',
  user: 
   { display_name: 'mono',
     screen_name: 'monochrm',
     klout_score: null,
     location_str: '画面の前',
     utc_offset: '32400' },
  venue_id: 1304409836517,
  match_type: 'twitter',
  tweet_id: '116494264137023489',
  created_at_unix: 1316609371,
  meta: 
   { matchedPhrase: 'junk',
     venueName: 'deletemepls really long name' },
  tags: [ '' ],
  indexed_at_unix: 1316609416 }
```

Comment: Show the code used to create the object.

Comment: The object is created from a Mongoose DB read

Comment: That isn't JSON. JSON requires property name to be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ text: 'stuff',
  user: 'user1'
}
```

You left off an apostrophe.

Now that you've posted your full JS code (that's not JSON, as @josnidhin points out)... works fine in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Rs9R4/ I don't believe a JS Object has .length, just Arrays.

Comment: Now that you've posted your full JS code (that's not JSON, as @josnidhin points out)... works fine in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Rs9R4/ I don't believe a JS Object has .length, just Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The json seems to be invalid

```
{
    "text": "stuff",
    "user": "user1"
}
```

Comment: It's invalid JSON but perfectly valid JavaScript that `node.js`'ll be fine with (once he adds the apostrophe).

Comment: It's fine in node.js code, but JSON.parse() will throw an error unless it's strictly valid JSON.

Comment: Sure, but as it's `node.js` code, I suspect he's not actually intending to write JSON, just a JSO with no N :-). The two seem to be frequently confused.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted your object into a FireBug console and it recognized it.

If you need to count the number of key/value pairs, you can use a function such as this one to do it:

```
function numMembers(o) {
    var i=0;
    for (a in o) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

You should be able to access the value of the text property via jsonObj.text. Are you sure that your object is being referenced by jsonObj? Also, can you access the values for simpler objects such as the ones mentioned in other posts if you create them? Furthermore, does anything work if you use only ASCII characters? For some reason, it might not be handling some of the non-Latin characters properly.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you have is not JSON because JSON requires property name to be in double quotes. It is a valid JavaScript object literal though, so I'll assume that's how you're using it.

Secondly, JavaScript objects in general do not have a `length` property. Arrays do.

There's no problem with your object literal so there must be some other problem elsewhere in your code.